# BB.DD en django

Tags: python, django

hay un error que me lanza Django a la hora de crear tableros para las bases de datos:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class tabla_prueba(models.Model):
    campo_uno=models.CharField(max_lenght=10)
    campo_dos=models.IntegerField(max_lenght=5)
    campo_tres=models.CharField(max_lenght=20)
```

El caso es que me lanza este error cuendo quiero usar el atributo **max_lenght** despues de utilizar el comando **py manage.py makemigrations**

```
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 984, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_lenght'
```

y no entiendo por que si en la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#charfield) dice que debo usar ese tributo

Answer (score 1):

El error te dice que esta recibiendo un argumento inesperado que es: 
**max_lenght** 
 
El error surge porque escribiste mal **max_length**, Tu escribiste:
**max_lenght**

Y el correcto sería:
**max_length**
El problema está en las últimas tres letras **gth**.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: vale vale, fallo muy tonto muchas gracias!!!